# Fabricate isn't saving attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I am having trouble getting one of my rspec/capybara integration specs to pass using the Fabricate gem.

Here is my spec:

```
it "shows current node as top node on page" do
  @node = Fabricate(:node)
  visit node_path(@node)
  page.should have_content(@node.title)
end
```

My Fabricator:

```
Fabricator(:node) do
  title { Faker::Lorem.words(3).join(" ") }
  description {Faker::Lorem.paragraphs(3).join("\n") }
end
```

My node's show action:

```
def show
  @node = Node.find(params[:id])
end
```

My show.html.haml:

```
%h1= @node.title
```

The output of my spec:

```
1) Node shows current node as top node on page
     Failure/Error: page.should have_content(@node.title)
       expected #has_content?("nostrum qui sed") to return true, got false
```

And lastly, I put a save_and_open_page, a debug(params) and debug(@node) on the view, here's that output:

```
action: show
controller: nodes
id: "1"

--- !ruby/object:Node 
attributes: 
  id: "1"
  title: 
  description: 
  created_at: 2011-06-01 03:14:45.645663
  updated_at: 2011-06-01 03:14:45.645663
attributes_cache: {}

changed_attributes: {}

destroyed: false
marked_for_destruction: false
new_record: false
previously_changed: {}

readonly: false
```

Anybody have any idea why title and description are not being saved to the DB?

Thanks in advance!

----------------- update 6-1 ------------------------

My node model:

```
class Node < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :title, :description
  validates :title, :presence => true
  validates :description, :presence => true
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In between

```
@node = Fabricate(:node)
visit node_path(@node)
```

Try inserting a save! to see if it's a validation issue of some kind:

```
@node = Fabricate(:node)
@node.save!
visit node_path(@node)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably do a:

```
class Node < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :description
  validates :title, :presence => true
  validates :description, :presence => true
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Model should be

```
    class Node < ActiveRecord::Base
      validates :title, :presence => true
      validates :description, :presence => true
    end
```